# Beamer: problems with \only, \pause, and fixed spacing

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, overlays, pause

I have a slide with three blocks, say 1, 2, 3a, and 3b, where 3a and 3b have exactly the same height (they are the same equation with some change of variable). I want to use `\pause` and `\only` to obtain the following:

- only 1
- (click) -> only 1 and 2
- (click) -> 1, 2, and 3a
- (click) -> 1, 2, and 3b

while maintaining the exact same positioning of each block as in the last two slides. Here is my tentative example: what happens is that Block 1 and Block 2 appear in the center of the slide as no third block is going to appear.

```
\begin{frame}[c]{Title}
    Block 1
        \pause
    Block 2
        \pause
    \only<3>{
        Block 3a
    }
    \only<4>{
        Block 3b
    }
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `overlayarea`-environment might do the trick

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \onslide<1->{1}

    \onslide<2->{2}

    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}

        \only<3>{3a} 

        \only<4>{3b}

    \end{overlayarea}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\only<3>{Block 3a}% no following empty line!  
\onslide<4>{Block 3b}
```

instead of `\only`. Then the vertical space of the invisible overlays is taken into account. An alternative is

```
Block 2 \pause

Block 3\only<3>{a}\only<4>{b}
```

Comment: Then the `Block 3b` is set below `Block 3a`... perhaps I misinterpret the OP, but I think he wants `Block 3b` to replace `Block 3a` exactly...

Comment: @darthbith is right.

Comment: @ItaAtz: see edited answer. Only the last should be `\onslide`

Comment: @Herbert: for some reason, the spacing in the third slide is all messed up, whereas it's right again in the fourth slide.

Comment: @ItaAtz: Delete the empty line between <3> and <4>. See above